# axios interceptor issue react redux and node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I created a custom hook and created an axios instance in it for fetching new tokens whenever the access token expires , initially on the page load the token seems to be fine , but after the timex expires my token is not getting set whats wrong in my code .

This is my useAxiosInstance.js file

```
import axios from "axios";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { authSuccess } from "../redux/auth/authSlice";
let userData = localStorage.getItem("userData")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"))
  : null;
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: userData?.accessToken
      ? `Bearer ${userData.accessToken}`
      : "",
  },
});

const useAxiosInstance = () => {
  const getTokens = async (data) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}refresh`,
        data,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      return res.data;
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  };

  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
      const accessTokenExpiryDate = jwtDecode(userData?.accessToken);

      console.log(accessTokenExpiryDate,"ex")

      if (accessTokenExpiryDate.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) {
        const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await getTokens(
          JSON.stringify({ token: userData.refreshToken })
        );

        userData = {
          ...userData,
          accessToken,
          refreshToken,
        };
        localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(userData));
        config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
  );

  return userData;
};

export default useAxiosInstance;
```

This is my app.js file

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "./app.less";
import Header from "./components/header/Header";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { authSuccess } from "./redux/auth/authSlice";
import AppRoute from "./routes/AppRoute";
import useAxiosInstance from "./utilities/useAxiosInstance"

function App() {
  const theme = useSelector((state) => state.theme);
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userData = useAxiosInstance();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(authSuccess(userData));
  }, [userData, dispatch]);


  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div
        className={theme.mode === "dark" ? "dark-mode app" : "light-mode app"}
      >
        {auth?.data && <Header />}
        <ToastContainer />
        <AppRoute />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my auth slice file

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  data: null,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    authSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.data =action.payload
    },
    authLogout: (state, action) => {
      state.data = null;
    },
  },
});

export const { authSuccess, authLogout } = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

this is my user slice file

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { showToast } from "../../utilities/toast";
import { authLogout } from "../auth/authSlice";
import { axiosInstance } from "../../utilities/useAxiosInstance";



const initialState = {
  update: { loading: false, data: null, error: null },
  get: { loading: false, data: null, error: null },
  delete: { loading: false, data: null, error: null },
};

export const getUser = createAsyncThunk("user/getUser", (payload) => {
  const { data, mode } = payload;
  return axiosInstance
    .get(`/user/${data?._id}`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + data.accessToken,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((error) => {
      showToast(error.response.data.message, mode, "error");
      throw error.response.data.message;
    });
});

export const deleteUser = createAsyncThunk("user/deleteUser", (payload) => {
  const { auth, navigate, mode, dispatch } = payload;

  return axiosInstance
    .delete(`/user/${auth._id}`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.accessToken,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      showToast("Deleted Successfully!", mode, "success");
      dispatch(authLogout());
      localStorage.removeItem("userData");
      navigate("/");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      showToast(err?.response?.data?.message, mode, "error");
      throw err.response.data.message;
    });
});

export const editUser = createAsyncThunk("user/editUser", (payload) => {
  const { form, data, mode } = payload;

  return axiosInstance
    .put(`/user/${data._id}`, form, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        // Authorization: "Bearer " + data.accessToken,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      showToast("Updated Successfully!", mode, "success");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      showToast(err?.response?.data?.message, mode, "error");
      throw err.response.data.message;
    });
});

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getUser.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.get.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(getUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.get.loading = false;
      state.get.data = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(getUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.get.loading = false;
      state.get.error = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(editUser.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.update.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(editUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.update.loading = false;
      state.update.data = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(editUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.update.loading = false;
      state.update.error = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(deleteUser.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.delete.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(deleteUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.delete.loading = false;
      state.delete.data = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(deleteUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.delete.loading = false;
      state.delete.error = action.payload;
    });
  },
});

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

since i am calling getUser api on page load its calling the custom hook but for edit and delete only till the access token exists its working and rest of the time , my new token is not getting updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is,the `userData` within the scope of this interceptor will not automatically update when you fetch new tokens because it's set outside of the interceptor function. This can lead to the old token being used repeatedly, causing the problems you're seeing.

You can modify your interceptor as following,

```js
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    // Retrieve the latest userData from localStorage
    let currentUserData = localStorage.getItem("userData")
      ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"))
      : null;

    // Decode the token to check its expiration
    const accessTokenExpiryDate = jwtDecode(currentUserData?.accessToken);

    // If the token has expired, refresh it
    if (accessTokenExpiryDate.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) {
      const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await getTokens(
        JSON.stringify({ token: currentUserData.refreshToken })
      );

      // Update userData with the new tokens
      currentUserData = {
        ...currentUserData,
        accessToken,
        refreshToken,
      };

      // Save the updated userData to localStorage
      localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(currentUserData));

      // Update the Authorization header with the new token
      config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
    } else {
      // If the token hasn't expired, use the current token
      config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + currentUserData.accessToken;
    }
    
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are managing and updating the user data (which includes access tokens) in your `useAxiosInstance` hook. Let's review your code:

```
const useAxiosInstance = () => {
  const getTokens = async (data) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}refresh`,
        data,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      return res.data;
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  };

  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
      const accessTokenExpiryDate = jwtDecode(userData?.accessToken);

      if (accessTokenExpiryDate.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) {
        const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await getTokens(
          JSON.stringify({ token: userData.refreshToken })
        );

        userData = {
          ...userData,
          accessToken,
          refreshToken,
        };
        localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(userData));
        config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
  );

  return userData;
};
```

The **issue** might be related to the fact that you are returning `userData` directly from the hook, and it might not be updating when tokens are refreshed. The `userData` is assigned the initial value retrieved from local **storage** only once when the hook is initialized. Subsequent updates to `userData` inside the ***interceptor*** might not reflect in the return value.

To fix this, you should update the state inside the hook and return that state. Here's how you can modify your hook:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useAxiosInstance = () => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(localStorage.getItem("userData")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"))
    : null);

  const getTokens = async (data) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}refresh`,
        data,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );
      return res.data;
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  };

  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    async (config) => {
      const accessTokenExpiryDate = jwtDecode(userData?.accessToken);

      if (accessTokenExpiryDate.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) {
        const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await getTokens(
          JSON.stringify({ token: userData.refreshToken })
        );

        const updatedUserData = {
          ...userData,
          accessToken,
          refreshToken,
        };
        localStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(updatedUserData));
        setUserData(updatedUserData);
        config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => Promise.reject(error)
  );

  return userData;
};
```

With this change, the `userData` state will be updated whenever tokens are refreshed, and the updated state will be returned from the hook. This should ensure that your ***application uses the latest tokens after refresh***.

Comment: this works fine but the getTokens api is getting called 5-6 times or even more sometimes